# loop doesn't use buffer correctly

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, buffer

i'm building an app that show your weight every week and if what the difference is with last week.

I have a buffer to store the weight of last week, but ervery time it goes throug the loop it makes buffer[$week] 1 again. So it returns an array with the (example) $weight 140.0 and the $weightDif 139.

**UPDATE**
Now it shows the weight difference, but not the correct week numbers

```
public function highLow(){
        // get user id
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        // make new array for weight difference per week
        $weightDif = array();

        // get list of weights of user
        $challenges = Challange::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

        // make a buffer for previous values in the array
        $buffer = array();

        // check if week weight is higher or lower than last week
        foreach ($challenges as $challenge) {
            $week = $challenge->week;

            $weight = $challenge->weight;

            // set default value if buffer is not set
            if (!isset($buffer[$week])) {
                $buffer[$week] = $weight;
            }

            // weight difference
            $weightDif[$week]['weight'] = $weight;
            $weightDif[$week]['weightDif'] = $buffer[$week] - $weight;

            $week++;

            // add value to buffer so the next value can check if it's higher or lower.
            $buffer[$week] = $weight;

        }  
        // dd($weightDif);

        return $weightDif;      
    }
```

Frontend

````
@forelse($weightDif as $weeknumber => $week)            
            <tr>
                <td>{{$weeknumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $week['weight'] }}
                            @if ($week['weightDif'] < 0)
                                <span style="color:red;">&#9660 {{$week['weightDif']}}</span>
                            @elseif ($week['weightDif'] > 0)
                                <span style="color:green;">&#9660 {{$week['weightDif']}}</span>
                            @else
                                <span style="color:yellow;">&#9660 {{$week['weightDif']}}</span>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/challange/edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="top" title=""
                    data-original-title="Pas klantdossier aan"><i class="uil-pen"></i></a>
                    <a href="/challange/destroy" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="top" title=""
                    data-original-title="Verwijder klant" onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je deze klant wilt verwijderen?');"><i class="uil-trash-alt"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @empty
            <tr>
                <td>Geen challanges gevonden</td>
            </tr>
            @endforelse
```
````

Comment: Why is 1 your default value? Shouldn't default value be the weight of the first challenge in all challenges?

Comment: Please post the contents of `$challenges`

Comment: ```
#original: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 9
        "user_id" => 5
        "weight" => 114.7
        "week" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-03-18 09:01:58"
        "updated_at" => "2020-03-20 10:31:11"
      ]
```

Comment: Because there is no previous weight to check on at the first weigh in. I set the value to 1

Comment: @JeffreyvanderKruit then use `false` for the first weigh in, and have a condition that checks for that so that the difference in that case uses the current weight, netting in 0 change.

Comment: Exactly, you should do a check if previous weight exists before you compare. This thing with 1 being default seems a bit awkward.

Comment: But empty($buffer[$weight]) or !isset($buffer[$weight]) is a boolean, so the first time it sets value 1, because it's false. There is no value, but then just before the retun i give buffer a value of weight. Why does it set the value to 1 again in the second time it loops?

Comment: I think it sets a value for that $buffer[$week] and is loops tho the next challenge, where there is no week set, so it should look to the weight of the previous $buffer[$week]. So i that like if(!isset($buffer[$week - 1]) ?

Comment: @JeffreyvanderKruit Here `$buffer[$week] = 1;` you are setting it to `1`. Thats what us commenters are pointing out. Why not set it to the current weight so you have no difference (subtraction wise, meaning 0), like so `$buffer[$week] = $weight;`. So when the difference is calculated you net 0. .... In regards to this block `if (empty($buffer[$week])) {`  ..... Unless im understanding this all completely wrong,

Comment: Possibly at this point @JeffreyvanderKruit could you update your question and include in plain words or pseudo-code what you are trying to accomplish? Debugging code with no design plan is tricky at best. I'm sure you have one. It just needs to be included in your question. Some expected output and your source data would be helpful too.

Comment: I got it to show the weight difference, but now it doesn't show the correct week numbers. I Wil update my Question

Comment: I got it! I forgot to set {{$weeknumber}}. Thanks for your help guys!